# Programmatically create the iOS timer alert ?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

In the alert posted by the iOS system timer  , the alert stays on ( plays the sound + vibration ) until the user acts and presses the timer done okay button , no matter which app the person might be currently using. Is there a way in iOS to replicate this behavior ?

Comment: We can only call UILocalNotification. Notif Stays on + plays the sound + vibration all the while our app is in background - no such feature is available to us devs.

Comment: @SamB Yeah. Thanks. That is sad

Comment: I'm so glad this isn't a thing. I can only imagine how annoying it would get.

Comment: @AMomchilov Yeah it is annoying , but it will force the user to take an action. I guess apple won't approve it , but this was to be used as a personal app.

Comment: On the contrary, it would force me to uninstall the app :) You can probably do this if you jailbreak, if you're willing to go that far